# Output similarities found in two list

Tags: python, list, data-structures, syntax

Two questions.
1.My code contain two list

```
ListA = [[3, 5], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [5, 7], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6], [7, 5]]

ListB =[[0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [6, 4]]
```

I want it to output the similarities found between the two list:

```
[[3,5][4,4][4,5][4,6][5,3][5,4][5,5][5,6][6,4]]
```

`print(set(ListA]).intersection(ListB]))` didn't work. Any other solutions?

2.
I would also like it to output the numbers that are similar in index[0] of each brackets of two number found in both list.

`ListA` contain `[3,5][4,4][5,3][6,4]`
`ListB` contain `[3,1][4,2][5,2][6,4]`

Since `3,4,5,6` is found in index[0] (Or first number) of each bracket, the output would be.

```
[3,4,5,6]
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Are `ListA` & `ListB` always sorted?

Comment: No. But if they are, what would be your suggestion?

Comment: `[[3,4][4,4][4,5][4,6][5,3][5,4][5,5][5,6][6,4]]` => `TypeError`

Comment: Sorry the first one should be [3,5]. I edited that.

Comment: I just now saw the second part of your question... but why is `3` not also included?

Comment: God dammit i made so many mistakes. Thanks for pointing it out..

Comment: You're even adding more errors like the one I pointed out earlier that you still didn't fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension like this:

```
listA = [[4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6]]
listB = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6]]

common = [i for i in listA if i in listB]
```

It might not be the fastest method but unless you're working with huge lists, it's fine.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if it included some more information about the complexity, being O(n²), and what that means for larger (not just "huge") lists. Agreed that for the given example this is perfectly fine and much simpler than using `set`, though.

Answer (score 2):

Lists are not hashable, so you have to convert to `tuple`<sup>1)</sup> if you want to use `set.intersection`:

```
>>> set(map(tuple, ListA)).intersection(map(tuple, ListB))
set([(6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 6), (4, 5), (4, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (3, 5), (5, 3)])
```

And back to list, if you want:

```
>>> sorted(map(list, set(map(tuple, ListA)).intersection(map(tuple, ListB))))
[[3, 5], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [6, 4]]
```

Once you have that, you can get a `set` of the first elements for your second part.

```
>>> set(x[0] for x in _)  # _ being the previous result
{3, 4, 5, 6}
```

This may seem a bit complicated, but using `set` it's faster, O(n), than a linear search in the entire list for each element, being O(n²).

---

Without using `set.intersection`, you could also use a list comprehension to filter those elements in `ListB` that are also in `ListA` (or vice versa), but again, you should convert the other list to a `set` so the lookup is faster (O(1) instead of O(n)), and for this, you again have to convert to `tuple`. (In this case, you could also convert to `repr` and compare those, but I tried both and `tuple` seems to be much faster.)

```
>>> setA = set(map(tuple, ListA))
>>> [b for b in ListB if tuple(b) in setA]
[[3, 5], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [6, 4]]
```

This also has the advantage of retaining the original order of the elements in `ListB` and is also a bit faster. Alternatively, you could create a dictionary mapping the first elements in the list to sets of the respective second elements, and then use a list comprehension, checking in that dict whether the element exists.

```
dictA = {}
for (x, y) in ListA:
    dictA.setdefault(x, set()).add(y)
common = [b for b in ListB if b[0] in dictA and b[1] in dictA[b[0]]]
```

This should be equally fast, i.e. O(n), and might need a bit less memory for creating all those sets (depending on the elements in the list).

---

<sup>1)</sup> Or any other unambiguous hashable representation of the lists, but `tuple` really seems to be the only viable option. `frozenset` does not care about the order of elements, and while you `could` convert to the lists `repr` and `eval` back after the intersection, you really shouldn't.

Comment: @StefanPochmann No, I agree that I was a bit inaccurate, though. Still, I don't see a viable alternative to `tuple`: `frozenset` does not respect order, and `str`... well, you _could_ convert to `repr` and then `eval` back to list, but... seriously?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Of course they don't "have to". OP can also just shut down the computer and go for a walk (hey, it's snowing!), but what's the point?

Comment: Not sure why you bring up something that wouldn't solve their problem and that has nothing to do with using `set.intersection`.

Answer (score 0):

Your original idea doesn't work because you can't have lists in sets, as they aren't hashable. 
An easy way is to turn your lists into tuples :

```
ListA = [[4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6]]
ListB =[[0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [6, 4]]

set_a = set([tuple(l) for l in ListA])
set_b = set([tuple(l) for l in ListB])

intersection = set_a.intersection(set_b)
print(intersection)
# {(6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 6), (5, 5), (4, 5), (5, 6), (4, 4)}

# or, if you prefer a list of lists
print([list(t) for t in intersection])
# [[6, 4], [5, 4], [4, 6], [5, 5], [4, 5], [5, 6], [4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use straightforward nested loops. Example is [here](https://trinket.io/python/5e3137dcd9)

```
firstIsEqual = set()
allEquals = []

for Av1, Av2 in ListA:
  for Bv1, Bv2 in ListB:
    if Av1 == Bv1:
      firstIsEqual.add(Av1)
      if Av2 == Bv2:
        allEquals.append([Av1, Av2])

print(firstIsEqual)
print(allEquals)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some confusion at the second part, Are you looking for this?

```
ListA = [[3, 5], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [5, 7], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6], [7, 5]]

ListB =[[0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [6, 4]]

from itertools import groupby
def similiraty(list_1,list_2):
    final_list = [i for i in list_1 if i in list_2]
    for a,b in groupby(final_list,lambda x:x[0]):
        print({a:list(b)})





print(similiraty(ListB,ListA))
```

output:

```
{3: [[3, 5]]}
{4: [[4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6]]}
{5: [[5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6]]}
{6: [[6, 4]]}
```

or simply:

```
return [a for a,b in groupby(final_list,lambda x:x[0])]
```

output:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```